# Adding lists in 2D lists

Tags: python, list

```
marks = [[12,14,8,7,17],[6,8,5,3,13],[16,15,9,10,18]]

total = 0
for s in range(3):
    for m in range(5):
        total[s] = total[s] + marks [s][m]
        print("total for student",s,"is",total[s])
```

Why does this throw the error below?

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Maybe because `total` is an int and you can not call `[s]` on int?...

Comment: I am so what must I do?

Comment: Use `total += marks[s][m]` instead.

Comment: that still throws an error

Comment: simply change total to a list ,  `total = []`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could simplify your code and make it work

**Code:**

```
marks = [[12,14,8,7,17],[6,8,5,3,13],[16,15,9,10,18]]    
total = 0
for s in range(len(marks)):
    print("total for student",s,"is",sum(marks[s]))
```

**Output:**

```
total for student 0 is 58
total for student 1 is 35
total for student 2 is 68
```

Making changes to your code

**Code1:**

```
marks = [[12,14,8,7,17],[6,8,5,3,13],[16,15,9,10,18]]


for s in range(3):
    total = 0
    for m in range(5):
        total += marks [s][m]
    print("total for student",s,"is",total)
```

**Notes:**

- Since you are trying to calculate the sum of a list you could use `sum` method

Comment: I want total for student 0 is 58
total for student 1 is 35
total for student 2 is 68

Comment: @AlanRobinson isn't the output I have given here ?

Comment: months=["Jan","Feb","March","April"]
temp =[]
a = 0
for each in months:
    temp = int(input("please enter a number for ",months[a]))
    a = a + 1

Comment: @AlanRobinson I can't get you there

Answer (score 0):

You do not need indeed to know the length of your list, if you will run through it. If you are doing it for indexing, use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?#enumerate) instead.

And, as The6thSense said, use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) for calculate each student's list

Tip: Use of [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html?#string.Formatter.format) makes your code more elegant! :-)

```
marks = [[12,14,8,7,17],[6,8,5,3,13],[16,15,9,10,18]]

for index, student in enumerate(marks):
    print('Total for student {student} is {total}'.format(student=i, total=sum(j)))

Total for student 0 is 58
Total for student 1 is 35
Total for student 2 is 68
```